# Gravityview - Show payment status of another form

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I currently have Gravityview view which is getting the source from form A. However, I want to show if the current user has made a payment on form B. Obviously this can be fetched from the {payment_status} merge tag of form B. But How can I pull the data of form B onto the Gravity view custom content field of form A?

I've looked at the gform_entry_id_pre_save_lead hook but I think there's a better way. Thanks for your help in advance..

```
    add_filter( 'gform_entry_id_pre_save_lead', 'my_update_entry_on_form_submission', 10, 2 );
    function my_update_entry_on_form_submission( $entry_id, $form ) {
    $update_entry_id = rgpost( 'my_update_entry_id' );
    return $update_entry_id ? $update_entry_id : $entry_id;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the [Gravityview Multiple Forms](https://gravityview.co/extensions/multiple-forms/) Add-on or you can try adding the following code to your functions.php:

```
function gf_check_form($atts = array()) {
    $details = shortcode_atts( array(
        'form_id' => "",
        'user' => ""

    ), $atts );
    $form_id = $details['form_id'];
    $search_criteria = array(
        'status'        => 'active',
        'field_filters' => array(
            'mode' => 'all',
            array(
                'key'   => 'created_by',
                'operator'=> 'is',
                'value' => $details['user']
            )
        )
    );
    $entries = GFAPI::get_entries( $form_id, $search_criteria);
    foreach($entries as $entry){
       $paid .= 'Paid on '.date("F d, Y", strtotime($entry['date_created'])).'<br><br>';
    }
    return $paid;
}
add_shortcode( 'check_form', 'gf_check_form' );
```

You can then add the following shortcode to your Gravityview in a custom content field:

[check_form form_id="**Add the form ID of form B here**" user="{created_by:ID}"]

Comment: I solved this already using my own code but your solution is absolutely right. Thank you